# Using SVProgressHUD fails to build in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, svprogresshud

I have installed SVProgressHud to my Xcode project via cocoa pods but I am getting an error during build time. I have posted an image of the error I am getting. I am using swift 3 and Xcode 8. I have searched everywhere for a solution but can't find anything. The only issue I can think of is the SVProgressHud cocoa pod that I have installed is not compatible with swift 3 and Xcode 8. I tried to install an earlier version of SVProgressHud but it automatically updates to the latest. I really don't know where to go from here. Help would be very much appreciated! Thanks in advance

[image]

Edited:

[image: podfile]

[image: Adding to terminal]

Comment: try    pod 'SVProgressHUD', :git => 'https://github.com/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD.git'

Comment: @Sh_Khan I just tried that but I get [!] Error installing SVProgressHUD
[!] Failed to download 'SVProgressHUD'.

Comment: did you put use_frameworks! in top of podfile

Comment: @Sh_Khan yes I did but still no success. I get the same error message

Comment: @Sh_Khan I tried it with this pod 'SVProgressHUD', :git => 'https://github.com/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD.git' and it worked, But then I get the same build error that I mentioned in the post. Sorry just realised its the same link that you commented earlier. I mustn't had copied it properly

Comment: Show the code line(s).

Comment: @meaning-matters I've updated the post with what I have done so far. Its literally a new Xcode project so I haven't written any code yet. I wanted to install the pods first but I can't build with SVProgressHUD for some reason

Comment: I literally open Xcode project go to build or run and I get the error shown in the first image of this post @meaning-matters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to try an older version of the pod, you can visit here for list of versions/changelogs: https://cocoapods.org/pods/SVProgressHUD#changelog

and then in your podfile you can set the version like so:

```
pod 'SVProgressHUD', '2.2.1'
```

I was able to install the pod and build without issues on Xcode 9.2, so not sure if its and issue with xcode 8 or something else.  If its an option, why not update to 9.2?

Comment: Your a legend! Thanks mate it works. I tried to install an earlier version '2.0' before but it kept updating to the latest version '2.2.5'. Anyways thanks again